# How does the pronunciation of “dass” compare to “das”?

Tags: pronunciation

I’m reading a book in which these two words often occur right next to each other as so: “… dass das …”  Is there a difference in their pronunciation?  If so, how can I make that clear?  Do I need to use a certain pronunciation to differentiate it from a phrase like “… das das …” for example or is the context sufficient for that purpose?

Comment: You used an obsolet spelling: Since 1996 we don't write »daß« but »dass«. You can find the old spelling in books that are older than 20 years, but in modern German »daß« is considered to be wrong. I corrected your question.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I'm reading the German translation of the Book of Mormon if that puts things into better context.

Comment: In English, the past tense of *to read* has the same pronunciation as the colour *red* as well. Nobody has difficulties with parsing spoken sentences like "Last week, I read red books"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen https://youtu.be/KVN_0qvuhhw?t=5m53s

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference in pronunciation (not in *Hochdeutsch* at least), and you don't need to differentiate them, since grammar orders them. 
That is:

> das dass  (✗)

is forbidden by grammar rules. In  particular, *dass* requires a punctuation sign, in fact:

> das, dass
>   das. Dass
>   das; dass

are possible.

Comment: I would slightly disagree on pronunciation with regards to vocal length - *das* is spoken with a longer, sometimes even stretched vocal "a" compared to *dass* - Typically  overemphasized by teachers reading a dictation to their pupils to hint the difference.

Comment: Today's correct spelling is "dass"

Comment: @tofro: »Das« und »dass« werden genau gleich ausgesprochen. Die Aussprache, mit IPA-Symbolen geschrieben, lautet in beiden Fällen: [das]. Das ist ja auch genau der Grund, warum so viele Menschen diese beiden Wörter beim Schreiben vertauschen. (Möglicherweise gibt es in nördlicheren Regionen einen Unterschied, der kann aber auch nicht besonders groß sein)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich weise (nochmals) auf das verbreitete Dehnen des Vokals im *das* beim Diktieren hin. Mehr habe ich nicht geschrieben. Dass die beiden Wörter in "Alltagssprache" genau gleich gesprochen werden: Da bin ich vollkommen bei dir.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Nein, der Grund für die Falschschreibung ist eine Grammatikschwäche - wer Relativsätze nicht erkennen kann, kann auch *das* und *dass* nicht unterscheiden. Deswegen wird jeder vernünftige Deutschlehrer ein falsches *das/dass* auch nicht als Rechtschreibfehler, sondern als Grammatikfehler werten.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: You are completely right, and you speak right from my soul. Having been born in Bavaria, living here since more than 40 years and having a lot of friends from all regions of Germany, including the North of Germany, I can confirm that "das" and "dass" are *not* pronounced the same in practice, neither in North Germany nor in South Germany.

Comment: So is this answer incorrect?  Do the pronunciations differ?

Comment: I can also remember that in school teachers pronounced *das* with a longer *a* than then *dass*. In spoken German you will most of the time not notice a difference, though (depending on the dialect. It *is* pronounced differently in Bavarian dialects). The spelling rules say that you use "ss" for a unvoiced "s" after a short vowel and a "ß" behind a long one (*Fass*, *Fraß*, *Gruß*, *Kuss*, etc.). So going back from this rule you could say that the *a* in *dass* should be pronounced significantly shorter than the *a* in *das*, however, most of the time it isn't.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar The rule you quote only tells us that *dass* has a short *a* (as it should be written *daß* otherwise). This does not say anything about the length of *a* in *das*. There is a proper name *Dahs* that does have a long *a*. During my schooldays in northern Germany, I have never ever experienced a difference in pronounciation between *das* and *dass* (or *daß* back then), even in beginners dictation exercises. The words are also always referred to as "*das* mit *s*" vs. "*dass* mit Doppel-*s* (or formerly: *es-zet*)", never as "*das* mit langem *a*" vs. "*dass* mit kurzem *a*"

Comment: There's also a rule for doubling consonants. One could argue that it should be applied in this case, too, even though after the consonant no other vocal follows here (which would prove my point by indirect evidence). Be it as it may, your "I'm from northern Germany" argument has no significance here, as it doesn't prove anything. I, however, can tell you for sure that there *are* regions in Germany where *das* and *dass* are pronounced differently. And this answers the question whether they are *always* pronounced the same with a clear *in most parts of Germany, but not everywhere*.

Comment: Also, the overall answer to this question is: It doesn't matter. *Das* is an article or relative pronoun. *dass* is a conjunction. *Das* can be used to start a relative clause, *dass* can not. So this answer explains it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The unmarked and semi-clear pronunciation of both words is identical. In spite of *das* having only a single letter, the vowel is short which is common in one-syllable words (compare *es, des* which also have a short vowel and where the vowel length is phonetic). Which one is which is usually differed grammatically by the type of sentence they are in. So far the theory.

In practice, some additional effects come into play:

- Speakers have a tendency to reduce the vowel in *das* into something closer to *des* (with a shwa). Bavarians (and probably other southerners, too) may even reduce it to *’s*. *Dass* is hardly ever subject to reduction.
- When dictating, there can be a tendency to overstress the length of *das*’ *a* making it sound like *daas*.